# Are all student pilots required to have a TSA background check or just non-US Citizens?

Tags: faa-regulations, tsa

I know that non-US Citizens have to go through approval with the TSA before beginning flight training, however could one avoid that fee by waiting until after getting Citizenship to start flight training?

I am a Resident Alien and currently considering starting flight school, I'm just wondering if waiting until I apply for Citizenship in 2021 is worth doing or if I could start now.

My fear is that I am already 30 and would like to eventually get a position as a Part 135 pilot. I am worried that I am already too old to be making such a change and thus adding time would just be making the situation more hopeless than it may already be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page on the FAA [website](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/aam/ame/guide/media/studentpilotrulechange.pdf) has details on getting your student pilot certificate.

> • Resident and US citizen student pilots follow [Student Pilot’s
> Certificate Requirements](https://www.faa.gov/pilots/become/student_cert/).
>
> • Foreign student pilots (non-resident) follow the [Alien Flight Student](https://www.flightschoolcandidates.gov/afsp2/?acct_type=c&section=WN) Program

It appears from your question that you should follow the same procedure as US citizens.

Refer to [AC 61-141](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/AC_61-141.pdf). Everyone must get a TSA screening before being issued a Student Pilot Certificate.

> **6.3 The Flight Instructor Verifies the Applicant’s Government-Issued Photo ID.**
>
> The flight instructor verifies the applicant’s identity and
> enters information from the applicant’s ID. If the applicant cannot
> present acceptable ID, discontinue the application process. Verify
> that the applicant has entered a correct date of birth. IACRA will not
> process an application unless the applicant is within 90 calendar-days
> of his or her 14th birthday or older. If the applicant is not of
> sufficient age, discontinue the application.
>
> **7.8 TSA Security Vetting and Temporary Certificate Availability of the Paper Method.**
>
> Provided the applicant is not deemed a security
> risk and is at least 14 years of age, the Airmen Certification Branch
> issues a permanent Student Pilot Certificate and mails it to the
> applicant. Applicants must also wait to receive a permanent plastic
> certificate in the mail.

Comment: What led to question is that the AFSP program linked to in the above document states _"Who must participate in the Alien Flight Student Program? Persons seeking flight training must submit a request if they are not citizens or nationals of the U.S."_ and being a resident alien I am neither a National nor a US Citizen. However, this does answer the question that everyone has to go through the TSA check.